# Why Netcat doesn't output anything

Tags: networking, netcat

I am running the following command on Manjaro:
`nc -lvnp 1337`
It doesn't output anything at all.

It should respond `listening on [any] 1337...`
The task manager shows that the process is taking up memory.
I try to ignored the lack of a response and tried to see the answer I need from the program, but it also doesn't display anything.